# Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut for an application menu item in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an application that has menu items that do not have keyboard shortcuts on them.

I'd like to add my own shortcut to run that menu item. In OSX there is a Keyboard panel that lets you define keyboard shortcuts for any application menu item. Is there something like that for Windows?

My question is different than the question marked as a [possible duplicate[1](https://superuser.com/questions/1106135/how-to-launch-an-application-with-a-keyboard-shortcut). That questions answers how to launch an application. My question asks how to execute a menu item.

A menu item is the text that runs an action of the application when it is selected. It often runs along the top of the application and can have sub menu items.

An example of this is the File menu common to many applications. A menu item or sub menu item would be File > Save.

My question is asking if there is a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to launch the menu item or sub menu item.

Comment: It depends on the application. Your question is too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch an application with a keyboard shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106135/how-to-launch-an-application-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: @DavidPostill I've updated the details in my question and harry was able to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
to set up shortcuts for the menus for a specified windows.
Its website contains many tutorials that will get you started.

The command to use is 
[WinMenuSelectItem](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMenuSelectItem.htm)
whose syntax is:

> WinMenuSelectItem, WinTitle, WinText, Menu , SubMenu1, SubMenu2, SubMenu3, SubMenu4, SubMenu5, SubMenu6, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText

Examples:

```
; This will select File->Open in Notepad:
WinMenuSelectItem, Untitled - Notepad, , File, Open

; Same as above except it's done by position vs. name:
WinMenuSelectItem, Untitled - Notepad, , 1&, 2&
```